# Extract case statement and string start with $ from nvp_add function in loop...

Tags: python, string, instance, extract, file-io

I have 1 ascii plain input text file as below with many case, I'm giving here 2 switch case. What i need is i need to extract all strings start with '$' in details function (as bold) in textfile below and put in new file 1. Then i need to extract all strings start with '$' in nvp_add function (as bold) in textfile below and put in new file 2. Desperately need help!!!..I'm expecting for output like this:

Expected output to be in File 1:

```
case "11": ### eventDDoSLow

$severity, $description, $eventID, $eventURL, $alertLevel, $eventStart, 
$eventSourceCount

case "15": ### eventWormLow

$severity, $description, $eventID, $eventURL, $alertLevel, $eventStart, 
$eventSourceCount, $eventSourceTable, $eventDestCount, $eventDestTable, 
$eventProtocolCount, $eventProtocolTable, $eventServiceCount, $eventServiceTable,
$mazuSourceName
```

Expected output to be in File 2:

```
case "11": ### eventDDoSLow

$severity, $description, $eventID, $eventURL, $alertLevel, $eventStart,
$eventSourceCount

case "15": ### eventWormLow

$severity, $description, $eventID, $eventURL, $alertLevel, $eventStart, 
$eventSourceCount, $eventSourceTable, $eventDestCount, $eventDestTable, 
$eventProtocolCount, $eventProtocolTable, $eventServiceCount, $eventServiceTable, 
$mazuSourceName
```

Input File (plain ascii):

```
switch($specific-trap)
{


case "11": ### eventDDoSLow

    ##########
    # $1 = severity
    # $2 = description
    # $3 = eventID
    # $4 = eventURL
    # $5 = alertLevel
    # $6 = eventStart
    # $7 = eventSourceCount
    # $8 = eventSourceTable
    # $9 = eventDestCount
    # $10 = eventDestTable
    # $11 = eventProtocolCount
    # $12 = eventProtocolTable
    # $13 = eventServiceCount
    # $14 = eventServiceTable
    # $15 = eventNormalBPS
    # $16 = eventCurrentBPS
    # $17 = eventNormalPPS
    # $18 = eventCurrentPPS
    ##########

    $severity = $1
    $description = $2
    $eventID = $3
    $eventURL = $4
    $alertLevel = lookup($5, AlertLevel)
    $eventStart = $6
    $eventSourceCount = $7
    $eventSourceTable = $8
    $eventDestCount = $9
    $eventDestTable = $10
    $eventProtocolCount = $11
    $eventProtocolTable = $12
    $eventServiceCount = $13
    $eventServiceTable = $14
    $eventNormalBPS = $15
    $eventCurrentBPS = $16
    $eventNormalPPS = $17
    $eventCurrentPPS = $18

    include "$NC_RULES_HOME/include-snmptrap/riverbed/riverbed-  
    MAZU-MIB.parser.include.snmptrap.rules"

    @URL = $eventURL

    $OS_EventId = "SNMPTRAP-riverbed-MAZU-MIB-eventDDoSLow"

    @AlertGroup = "Denial Of Service"
    @AlertKey = "Event ID: " + $eventID
    @Summary = "Denial of Service  ( Src: " + $mazuSourceName + ", Dest: " + 
    $mazuDestName + " )" + " ( " + @AlertKey + " ) "

    $DEFAULT_Severity = 2
    $DEFAULT_Type = 1
    $DEFAULT_ExpireTime = 0               

    @Identifier = @Node + " " + @AlertKey + " " + @AlertGroup + " " + 
    $DEFAULT_Type + " " + @Agent + " " + @Manager + " " + $specific-trap

    $alertLevel = $alertLevel + " ( " + $5 + " )"
    if(match($OPTION_EnableDetails, "1") or   
    match($OPTION_EnableDetails_riverbed, "1")) {
        **details****($severity, $description, $eventID, $eventURL, $alertLevel, 
    $eventStart, $eventSourceCount)**
    }
    **@ExtendedAttr = **nvp_add**(@ExtendedAttr, "severity", $severity,
    "description", $description, "eventID", $eventID,
         "eventURL", $eventURL, "alertLevel", $alertLevel, 
     "eventStart", $eventStart,
         "eventSourceCount", $eventSourceCount)**

case "15": ### eventWormLow

    ##########
    # $1 = severity
    # $2 = description
    # $3 = eventID
    # $4 = eventURL
    # $5 = alertLevel
    # $6 = eventStart
    # $7 = eventSourceCount
    # $8 = eventSourceTable
    # $9 = eventDestCount
    # $10 = eventDestTable
    # $11 = eventProtocolCount
    # $12 = eventProtocolTable
    # $13 = eventServiceCount
    # $14 = eventServiceTable
    ##########

    $severity = $1
    $description = $2
    $eventID = $3
    $eventURL = $4
    $alertLevel = lookup($5, AlertLevel)
    $eventStart = $6
    $eventSourceCount = $7
    $eventSourceTable = $8
    $eventDestCount = $9
    $eventDestTable = $10
    $eventProtocolCount = $11
    $eventProtocolTable = $12
    $eventServiceCount = $13
    $eventServiceTable = $14

    include "$NC_RULES_HOME/include-snmptrap/riverbed/riverbed-
    MAZU-MIB.parser.include.snmptrap.rules"

    @URL = $eventURL

    $OS_EventId = "SNMPTRAP-riverbed-MAZU-MIB-eventWormLow"

    @AlertGroup = "Worm Detected"
    @AlertKey = "Event ID: " + $eventID
    @Summary = "Worm Detected  ( Src: " + $mazuSourceName + ", Dest: " + 
    $mazuDestName + " )" + " ( " + @AlertKey + " ) "

    $DEFAULT_Severity = 2
    $DEFAULT_Type = 1
    $DEFAULT_ExpireTime = 0               

    @Identifier = @Node + " " + @AlertKey + " " + @AlertGroup + " " + 
    $DEFAULT_Type + " " + @Agent + " " + @Manager + " " + $specific-trap

    $alertLevel = $alertLevel + " ( " + $5 + " )"
    if(match($OPTION_EnableDetails, "1") or 
    match($OPTION_EnableDetails_riverbed, "1")) {
        **details($severity, $description, $eventID, $eventURL, $alertLevel,
   $eventStart, $eventSourceCount, $eventSourceTable, $eventDestCount,   
   $eventDestTable, 
   $eventProtocolCount, $eventProtocolTable, $eventServiceCount, $eventServiceTable, 
   $mazuSourceName)**
    }
    **@ExtendedAttr = nvp_add(@ExtendedAttr, "severity", $severity, "description",   
   $description, "eventID", $eventID,
         "eventURL", $eventURL, "alertLevel", $alertLevel, "eventStart", $eventStart,
         "eventSourceCount", $eventSourceCount, "eventSourceTable", $eventSourceTable,
   "eventDestCount", $eventDestCount,
         "eventDestTable", $eventDestTable, "eventProtocolCount", $eventProtocolCount,
   "eventProtocolTable", $eventProtocolTable,
         "eventServiceCount", $eventServiceCount, "eventServiceTable",
   $eventServiceTable, "mazuSourceName", $mazuSourceName)**
```

Comment: - Your expected output File 1 and File 2 are identical as far as I can tell.  - You say "in bold" but there is nothing in bold.  - What did you try? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re


functions = ["details", "nvp_add"]
caselines_index = []
cases = []
readlines = []

def read(in_file):
  global cases
  global caselines_index
  global readlines
  with open(in_file, 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
      readlines.append(line.strip())
    for line in readlines:
      case_search = re.search("case\s\".+?\"\:\s", line)
      if case_search:
        caselines_index.append(readlines.index(line))
    print caselines_index
    caselines_index_iter = iter(caselines_index)
    int_line_index = int(next(caselines_index_iter))
    int_next_index = int(next(caselines_index_iter))
    while True:
      try:
        case_text = ' '.join(readlines[int_line_index:int_next_index]).strip()
        case = [readlines[int_line_index].strip(), case_text]
        cases.append(case)
        int_line_index = int_next_index
        int_next_index = int(next(caselines_index_iter))
      except StopIteration:
        case_text = ' '.join(readlines[int_line_index:len(readlines) - 1]).strip()
        case = [readlines[int_line_index].strip(), case_text]
        cases.append(case)
        break

def work():
  for func in functions:
    with open(func+".txt", 'w+') as result_file:
      for case_list in cases:
        caseline = case_list[0].strip()
        result_file.write(caseline + "\n")
        nvp = re.findall(func+"\(.+?\)", case_list[1].strip())

        for item in nvp:
          result_list = re.findall("(\$.+?)[\,\)]", item)

          for result in result_list:
            if "$*" not in result:
              result_file.write(result + "\n")

def main():
  in_file = "input.txt"
  read(in_file)
  work()


if __name__=="__main__":
  main()
```

try this, even though i think i saw a similar question by you a while ago.